# Text box already present do nothing on button click in javascript

Tags: jquery

I have a button named Rename. onclick of that button one text box appears and it comes every time when rename clicked. I want the text box appear once only until we rename the file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.renameClass').click(function(){
        //if text box already present do nothing 
        // otherwise... let it rename the file
        var domparent=$(this).parent();
        renameId = $(this).attr('id');
        var filename=$(this).parent().children("p.filename");
        text=filename[0].innerText;
        fullPathName=""+renameId+filename[0].innerText;
        var dom='<input type="text" class="rename" value='+text+' /> <button class="updateName" >Done</button><br>';
        $(domparent).append(dom);
    });
```

Comment: Please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), hopefully it will help you in formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
$("#show").hide();
var a=1;
$('.renameClass').click(function(){
if(a==1){
$("#show").show();/*show what you need to show*/
a=0;
}
});
```

you can make an element with the id 'show' with all the elements you need require and show it when neccessary!

Comment: Its not working ... saying that ("#show").hide() is not a function.

Comment: I didnt notice it but i had written the answer as #("#show").hide(); but it is $("#show").hide

Comment: Pls mark this answer as correct if you got the correct answer